# Texstudio crashing when my file is huge

Tags: texstudio

My texstudio is crashing whenever I do this:

I have a bunch of \input{files} because I'm writing a large document. When writing, I commented out most of the inputs to speed up the compile process. However, when I uncomment all the inputs, my texstudio crashes all the time. It seems like texstudio cannot handle the large files.

Anyway to overcome this problem?

Comment: what type of error are you getting? what does the log files say?

Comment: Texstudio just closes itself. Nothing generated. Now I'm editing in text and running in cmd.

Comment: Which version of TXS, what OS? You might try deactivating the `automatically load included files` option in `Configure TeXstudio -> Editor` (with `show advanced options` checked)

Comment: A few basics [1] estimate the final file size by binary chop, uncomment  half and if it does not fail look at result size and double it, if fails re comment a quarter so only 25% is processed if it works quadruple the result) [2] look for high res images, comment those out. Does it run? If so consider reducing dpi, same for any other large embedment [3] confirm the disk source/temp/target has no limitations e.g. free space

Comment: Thanks guys. After unchecking the automatically load include files, it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeXstudio does a lot of pre-loading, scanning and analyzing behind the scenes which may spell trouble if you are including many large files and/or if you have an old system.
You can turn off this option by deactivating `automatically load included files` in `Configure TeXstudio -> Editor` (with `show advanced options` checked on the bottom left corner of the Config dialog).
Then you should have a smoother experience with TXS / not have TXS crash so often.

In that case, you would have to keep the `\include`-d files open in TXS if you want to use any defined commands, labels etc. from that file and have them prompted to you by TXS.

[image]